# How to store a complex type with only one value in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF Code First and have an entity which has a Telephone property of type PhoneNumber. The PhoneNumber class has some validation and convenience methods, but essentially holds a string with a correct phone number.

I want to persist this to the database as a simple string. How would I go about this?

Do I need to register some sort of type converter, or do I really need to expose a public property on my PhoneNumber class which is used as complex type (I'd rather not have a public property like this, since I would like PhoneNumber to be immutable).

This is my PhoneNumber class:

```
public class PhoneNumber {
    private string _number;

    public PhoneNumber(string number) {
      if (!IsValid(number)) {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Dutch phone number.");
      }

      _number = number;
    }

    private static string Sanitize(string number) {
      return number.Trim()
        .Replace("-", String.Empty)
        .Replace(" ", String.Empty);
    }

    public bool IsValid() {
      return IsValid(this);
    }

    public static bool IsValid(string number) {
      if (number == null) {
        return false;
      }

      var cleanNumber = Sanitize(number);
      return Regex.IsMatch(cleanNumber, @"^06\d{8}$");
    }

    public static implicit operator PhoneNumber(string number) {
      return new PhoneNumber(number);
    }

    public static implicit operator string(PhoneNumber number) {
      return number.ToString();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm guessing it should be possible to annotate the properties you want persisted, but don't know how. Maybe you should try google: "entity framework annotate poco"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add this to your code:

```
public string Number
{
    get { return _number; }
    private set { _number = value; }
}

private PhoneNumber() {}
```

and map your class as complex type:

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<PhoneNumber>();
```